# How to properly conduct a paired sample test when the number of observations is around 10,000?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have paired samples $(X_1, \ldots, X_{10,000})$ and $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_{10,000})$. If I wanted to do a t-test or a bootstrap test for differences, would it be appropriate even to try doing a test because of how large the sample size is?

If I understand correctly, the p-value from tests for these usually will be a function of the sample size. What considerations should be given for such a test with such a large sample size?

Comment: Can you interpret the mean difference and its confidence limits in terms of their substantive contextual meaning?